# Execute command with procesBuilder

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder

For my application i use SUMO (an application that simulates traffic on a certain route).

When starting this program wih the right parameters it will generate an output. But starting this simulation must be done from the command line.
So i thought to solve this with a procesBuilder, but this didn't work. I found a lot of people having problems with this procesBuilder but i didn't understand after reading how to execute my commandline with it.

The command that needs to be executed is:

```
"sumo -c \"" + path + FILENAME_CONFIG + "\" --netstate-dump " + ouputPath"
```

Sumo is located at my desktop in

```
"C:\Users\Samee\Desktop\SUMO\sumo-0.17.0\bin"
```

Now i did solve this problem by putting the above information in a bat file and run the bat file. (While navigating with Cd .. and setting the path.
How i runned the bat file:

```
Process rt = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + generator.getPath() + Generator.FILENAME_BAT);
```

But i need to know when the simulation has stopped simulating.
Is this possible to solve with a `procesBuilder`?

Like:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sumo -c \"" + path + FILENAME_CONFIG + "\" --netstate-dump " + ouputPath);
```

And how do i know if the ProcessBuilder is done with executing?

Answer (score 0):

`ProcessBuilder` expects each parameter to supplied as a separate `String`

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "sumo.exe", 
    "-c", 
    path + FILENAME_CONFIG + "\", 
    "--netstate-dump", 
    ouputPath);
```

**Updated**

The command name should be `sumo.exe`.  Unless `sumo.exe` is within the OS's search path, the OS will not be able to run it.

Instead you will need to supply the absolute path `C:\\Users\\Samee\\Desktop\\SUMO\\sumo-0.17.0\\bin\\sumo.exe`

Comment: It doesn't work, but also got no exception. I tried it with absolute paths and builder.start();. From which path will the builder gets executed? Because it needs to be executed in: '"C:\Users\Samee\Desktop\SUMO\sumo-0.17.0\bin"' Do you know how?

Comment: It probably should be summo.exe

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to provide command line argument to your process. Provide Sting list, Process Builder has capability to parse argument from supplied list

```
final List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();                

commands.add("sumo");//commands.add("C:\Users\Samee\Desktop\SUMO\sumo-0.17.0\bin\sumo");
commands.add(" -c "); 
commands.add(path);
commands.add(FILENAME_CONFIG);
commands.add("--netstate-dump");
commands.add(ouputPath);
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
```

Comment: Yeah but this doesn't solve my problem, see my comment at the answer of madProgrammer. Its the same but then in a String array.

Comment: @Sameedhoe, if your **sumo** utility is not register in **Enviormnet variable**  then provide exact path of your binary of sumo.

Answer (score 0):

To check if an external process finished (and to capture output/exit value) you can do the following:

```
static public String runCmd(String... commands)
{
    final int BUFSIZE = 1024;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(BUFSIZE);
    int exitVal = -1;
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    try
    {
        Process p = builder.start();

        InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        char[] buf = new char[BUFSIZE];
        int len = -1;
        while (-1 != (len = isr.read(buf)))
        {
            sb.append(buf, 0, len);
        }
        exitVal = p.waitFor();

        p.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```